# Character model diffuse baking

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

First time using stackexchange, so bear with me. I'm making a mid-poly character in Blender 2.8 for a third person shooter in Unreal Engine 4. [image: Character model with separate materials]. While I am satisfied with the shading so far, the model takes up nearly 500 megabytes of memory, far too much for a game asset. I am using a combination of 1024 and 2048p resoultion PBR materials.I have been trying to bake a single diffuse, normal, roughness, and metallic map onto a copy of the model with a packed uv map and just a single material, however the resulting texture images look nothing like they should.[image: Result of diffuse bake] I'm really new to blender and just learning about how to use cycles baking, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the results you're getting?  nice model by the way. :)

Comment: So when I bake the diffuse textures from the original model onto the game model, I'll get this weird smearing in certain areas, notably around the face and eyes, and a pretty severe drop in resolution. I can't seem to find a metallic bake option in Blender cycles, either, but I would like to keep the pbr materials functional.